# Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement log in example using spring security so I flowed some tutorials and I have written this code so far:

Role.java:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String roleName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public Role(){}

    public Role(int id, String roleName, List<User> users) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.users = users;
      //all setter and getters 

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory factory;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String passowrd;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="UserAndRoles",
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus  status;
```

//constructor and setter, getters

}

Dao Class:

```
public interface UserDao {

    void addUser(User user);

    void editUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(int userId);

    User findUser(int userId);

    User findUserByName(String username);

    List<User> getAllUsers();

}
```

Dao Implementation:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {

        session.getCurrentSession().save(user);
        }
//all methods of Dao Class
    }
```

and userDetailsService class:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; 

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=userDao.findUserByName(username);

            if(user!=null)
            {


                String password=user.getPassowrd();

                boolean enabled=user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean accountNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
                boolean accountNonLocked = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);

                //populate user roles

                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for(Role role : user.getRoles()){

                    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRoleName()));
                }

                //create spring security object
                org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User securityUser = new 
                    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

                    return securityUser;
            }else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found !!!");
            }
    }

}
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:form-login />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />        
    </security:http>
  <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                    <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            </list>
        </property>
  </bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.dz.hrportal.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
     <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dz.hrportal.dao,com.dz.hrportal.dao.impl,com.dz.hrportal.service" />
```

and finally spring-servlet.xml:

```
<!-- Hibernate Configurations   -->
        <bean id="propertyConfigurer"    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
</bean> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="configLocation"     value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
              </props>
        </property>
```

above code which I written is executing successfully but it is not getting the login credentials.

I am using built int spring security's login form and I have created three tables in DB named as:

User ,
Role,
userAndRoles

still I am not able to login.

does anyone have the solution on this?

Comment: Why are u not using @Table annotation for Role class

Answer (score 1):

In mysql workbench `password` is not matched or you can't set the password for root `user`.

**Solution:**

1. Open Mysql workbench
2. Goto Manage DB Connections
3. In Left side menu click on localhost(connection name)
4. At password field click on `Store in Vault`, a popup window `Store Password For Connection` will be open.
5. Type the password as `password`

**Note:** If you enter `root` as **password** it may shown you an error better to use 8 length characters as password.

Comment: ,I think that is not the issue.I did change password of mysql but didn't work for me.....when I debug the code then I see the User user=userDao.findUserByName(username); is returning null ...any idea?

Comment: @user3264841 it means record does not exits in `user` table or else provide the same name in database records for name match.

Comment: yes I am pretty sure that I am using matching records.